# how to make a form independent application in vb6?

Tags: vb6

Actually i ' m trying to develop an application that pops a message whenever a removable media is inserted into the system.But the application is form dependent i.e. whenever i lost focus from the form where the code is provided, the application seems to halt.Please help.

thanks

Comment: You need to provide more information with code snippets and whatever information you have that can be helpfull for other to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an application without a form, create a sub main in a module like this:

```
Sub Main()
    'your code to run
End Sub
```

And define the startup form in the project properties as Sub Main. Execution of the program will end after the code in Sub Main has run.